# RequestMapping method is not being called by AJAX POST

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee

i have made a java web project which is annotations based and deployed it on tomcat 7. When I started the server the application launched with the URL: http://localhost:8080/myprojectName

but when i am making an AJAX request with the url that i have defined using request mapping it gives me an error  that the requested resource is not available.

Kindly help me with this as I am new to this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you could type down the code for the servlet/controller, then the error can be analysed. The url that you mentioned is nothing but the server and the context path of the deployed application. which may not be the servlet path.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String test() {
  System.out.println("Method executed");
  return "Success";
 }

Comment: This is one of the method in my controller and the url that i am trying to hit is http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/test

Comment: the exact code is @Controller
@RequestMapping("/eMudraRequest")
public class EMudraAppController {

Comment: If that's the case, your ajax url must point to the control url, not to the context url...  i.e the url should be `http://localhost:8080/myprojectName/eMudraRequest/test`. Assuming you have configured the spring context appropriately.

Comment: can you just let me know that how to check whether the spring context is configured properly or how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your time.